# Why are Amazon virtual private clouds non-transitive?

Tags: routing

Newbie question ... I know that Amazon VLANs (aka: VPCs) are non-transitive.  However, I was hoping someone could explain why a packet from a peered VLAN cannot access an internet gateway in another.   Also, apparently using a v-router to "hop" traffic from one VLAN to the other somehow makes the packets transitive.  Why?   Any light you could shed on this would be much appreciated.  Thanks a bunch for your time and help.  -- Lisa

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like normal VLAN behavior, although AMAZON private clouds are off-topic here. Traffic on a VLAN (layer-2 domain) cannot get to another VLAN unless it goes through a layer-3 device, e.g. router.

Don't confuse the network layers. Layer-2 addresses, e.g. MAC addresses, are used in layer-2 frames to get traffic from one device to another device on the same LAN (or VLAN). Layer-3 addresses, e.g. IP addresses, are used to route layer-3 packets between LANs. Bridges, including switches, switch frames on a LAN. Routers route packets between LANs.

Comment: Also, think about it from Amazon's point of view. They already offer a routed service, using a global routed network called "the Internet". It's a LAN service behind the enterprise firewall which many of their cloud-using customers desire. That this can't be routed is a win: it limits the enterprise's exposure to Amazon to just the devices on that VLAN. A routed service wouldn't be nearly so useful.